# Using Android Support Annotations

Tags: android, multithreading, android-support-library

I have an activity where I open a image picker intent and the when I get the selected `Uri`, I create a copy of the file in cache directory and then pass the location of the image to Picasso to load the image. I am doing this because some apps like Google Photos do not allow the actual Uris to be passed to different activities for security reasons.

Here is my code for the same :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_external_photo_share);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        LogUtil.i(TAG, "onCreate called");
        tinyDB = new TinyDB(this);
        if (tinyDB.getBoolean(AppConstants.LOGIN_STATE, false)) {
            imageUri = (Uri) getIntent().getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
            if (imageUri == null || imageUri.toString().isEmpty()) {
                ExternalPhotoShareActivity.this.finish();
            }
            String newActualPath = getActualPathFromUri(imageUri);
            Uri newUri = null;
            if (newActualPath != null) {
                newUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(newActualPath));
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(ExternalPhotoShareActivity.this, AddCaptionActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("externalImageUri", newUri);
            intent.putExtra("externalImagePath", newActualPath);
            startActivity(intent);
            ExternalPhotoShareActivity.this.finish();
        } else {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ExternalPhotoShareActivity.this);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_external_share_error);
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            dialog.show();

            TextView goBack = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView86);
            goBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        if(dialog != null) {
                            if(dialog.isShowing()) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        // Handle or log or ignore
                    } catch (final Exception e) {
                        // Handle or log or ignore
                    }
                    ExternalPhotoShareActivity.this.finish();
                }
            });
        }
    }

private String getActualPathFromUri(Uri selectedImageUri) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = getBitmapFromUri(selectedImageUri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (bitmap == null) {
            return null;
        }

        File imageFileFolder = new File(getCacheDir(), "galleri5");
        if (!imageFileFolder.exists()) {
            imageFileFolder.mkdir();
        }

        FileOutputStream out = null;

        File imageFileName = new File(imageFileFolder, "galleri5-" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(imageFileName);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        } finally {
            if (out != null) {
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return imageFileName.getAbsolutePath();
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
        ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor =
                getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
        assert parcelFileDescriptor != null;
        FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
        parcelFileDescriptor.close();
        return image;
    }
```

I call `getActualPathFromUri()` in my activity's `onCreate()` method. Sometimes, when the images from gallery are large, it takes some seconds to load the image on the screen. So, I thought about executing these two methods in background thread so that I could show the UI while the background work is done.

I recently started using [Android Support Annotations](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/support-annotations) and tried to annotate the `getActualPathFromUri()` with `@WorkerThread`. But in my `onCreate()` method, it marks it red and says that this method should be called from Worker Thread, currently inferred thread is main.

What is the proper way of doing this? Should I even do it in background thread or not? Thanks.

Comment: @jonas.koeritz I added the onCreate() method. Please have a look.

Answer (score 3):

The annotations `@WorkerThread` or `@UIThread` are only used for flagging a method. Android Studio will raise an error when your method is called from a thread that does not match your annotated constraint. See [this documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/support-annotations).

For advice on threading with `AsyncTask` see [this android developers blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2009/05/painless-threading.html).

Comment: That is fine, but what should I do? And how should I do it? I don't want to use AsyncTask.

Comment: @AmitTiwari you will have to use an AsyncTask. Why would you want to omit that?

Comment: I don't really like the syntax.

Comment: I'm afraid an `AsyncTask` is the simplest way to go.

Comment: Is there any alternative to AsyncTask? May be in Rx-Java?

Comment: You could always use a simple Java Thread (`new Thread(new Runnable() { ... }).start()`) but AsyncTask will do all the dirty work for you.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, with the annotation `@WorkerThrad` you're saying that `getActualPathFromUri()` should only be called from a worker thread. As you're calling it from `onCreate()` which runs inside the UI-thread, lint detects the issue and flags it.

The fact that you annotate the method like that, does not mean you're running the method inside a worker thread. Annotation in this case is just a way to flag the developer (that might be different than yourself if working in a team) that a particular method is meant to be called in a particular thread.

If you want to actually run that method in an actual worker thread, just call it inside an `AsyncTask#doInBackground` method.

EDIT: if you don't wanna use `AsyncTask` you can use any other Android threading mechanism, like `IntentService`, `GcmTaskService` and whatnot but, you should not run it inside the UI thread because it may cause jank.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. I thought annotating it would allow me to skip AsyncTask.